# HTTP/2 over TLS for static landing page. Is it worth it?

Tags: http, ssl, http2

So I'm running a static landing page for a product/service I'm selling, and we're advertising using AdWords & similar. Naturally, page load speed is a huge factor here to maximize conversions.

Pros of HTTP/2:

1. Data is more compressed.
2. Server Push allows to send all resources at once without requests, which has MANY benefits such as replacing base64 inline images, sprites...etc.
3. Multiplexing over a single connection significantly improves load time.

Cons of HTTP/2:

1) Mandatory TLS, which slows down load speed.

So I'm torn. On one side, HTTP/2 has many improvements. On the other, maybe it would be faster to keep avoiding unnecessary TLS and continue using base64/sprites to reduce requests.

The total page size is ~1MB.

Would it be worth it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evidence is that reducing load speed is definitely worth the effort ([see the business case for speed](http://www.bookofspeed.com/chapter1.html)).

The TLS session is a pain and it is unfortunate that the browser vendors are insisting on it, as there is nothing in HTTP2 that prevents plain text.    For a low load system, were CPU costs are not the limiting factor, TLS essentially costs you one RTT (round trip time on network).

HTTP/2 and specially HTTP/2 push can save you many RTTs and thus can be a big win even with the TLS cost.    But the best way to determine this is to try it for your page.   Make sure you use a HTTP/2 server that supports push (eg Jetty) otherwise you don't get all the benefits.  [Here is a good demo](https://webtide.com/spdy-push-demo-from-javaone-2012/) of push with SPDY (which is that same mechanism as in HTTP/2):

Answer (score 1):

The performance impact of TLS on modern hardware [is negligible](https://istlsfastyet.com/).  Transfer times will most likely be network-bound.  It is true that additional network round-trips are required to establish a TLS session but compared to the time required to transfer 1MB, it is probably negligible (and TLS session tickets, which are widely supported, also save a round-trip).

Comment: I totally agree. Only small embedded devices might run into problems but I am sure they can use a board for that.

Answer (score 0):

How many HTTP requests does these 1000 kb require? With a page that large, I don't think it matters much for the end user experience.  TLS is here to stay though... I don't think you should NOT use it because it may slow your site down. If you do it right, it won't slow your site down.

Read more about SSL not being slow anymore: https://istlsfastyet.com/

Comment: I understand that there are arguments that SSL isn't really that slow, but since SSL requires more requests and data to be transferred, implementing SSL on your site will always slow it down, even if it's by a very small amount.

Unfortunately, studies have shown that even absurdly small (like 10ms) delays have negative effect on bounce rates.

This is ESPECIALLY a problem for static sites that do not feature any sort of payment checkout system. My site links to PayPal/Amazon.

My site is literally a single page with static text, i don't need SSL.

Comment: I would not use SSL in your case either :) Feels a bit overkill for a static page. You would probably get a faster page more easily by loading some content after the DOM is loaded, like lazy load, than you would accomplish by HTTP/2.

Answer (score 0):

Mandatory TLS doesn't slow down page load speed if it's SPDY/3.1 or HTTP/2 based due to both supporting multiplexing request streams. Only non-SPDY or non-HTTP/2 based TLS would be slower than non-https.

Check out https://community.centminmod.com/threads/nginx-spdy-3-1-vs-h2o-http-2-vs-non-https-benchmarks-tests.2543/ clearly illustrates why SPDY/3.1 and HTTP/2 over TLS is faster for overall page loads. HTTP/2 allows multiplexing over several hosts at same time while SPDY/3.1 allows multoplexing per host.

Best thing to do is test both non-https and HTTP/2 or SPDY/3.1 https and see which is best for you. Since you have a static landing page it makes testing that much easier to do. You can do something similar to page at https://h2ohttp2.centminmod.com/flags.html where you setup both HTTP/2, SPDY and non-https on same server and be able to test all combinations and compare them.